# Unable to create an archive (IOS) in azure pipelines

Tags: ios, flutter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create an IPA in azure pipelines, but the Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-build.FlutterBuild@0 task fails with the below error,

```
/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal error: module 'app_settings' not found
    @import app_settings;


Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'app_settings' not found
/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8

Encountered error while building for device.
##[error]Error: The process '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Flutter/3.0.5/macos/flutter/bin/flutter' failed with exit code 1
```

This is the code added for the task,

```
- task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-build.FlutterBuild@0
    displayName: "iOS - build ipa"
    inputs:
      target: "ios"
      buildFlavour: ${{ parameters.appSuffix }}
      entryPoint: ${{ parameters.flavorEntryPoint }}
      iosCodesign: false
```

Please note that this application works perfectly on the local machine(can build and create an ipa). Anything I have done wrong? I also followed deleting pod files and regenerating them (following almost all the answers posted in stackoverflow and other threads) but still no luck! Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since I was using flavors in my application, this was probably because the configuration names I have set are not similar to the ones I've created in the schemes. Please make sure the scheme names and the project configuration for build types are identical.